# How to solve this Laplace integral for an averaging function in an iterative numerical (finite difference) model?

Tags: laplace-transform, moving-average, integration, finite-differences

I am trying to implement a mathematical model for vibrational damping described in [this article](http://140.121.146.149/JSV-Muravskii%20-2004.pdf).

They provide an equation for damping force ($F$) as a function of:

- a spring constant ($k$)
- a damping coefficient ($η$)
- displacement of the point being damped ($x$)
- velocity of that point ($\dot{x}$)
- mean displacement and velocity for the point ($x_m$ and $\dot{x}_m$)

I understand the basic principle of the force equation. However, my math is not very advanced, and I don't understand how they calculate the mean displacement and velocity ($x_m$ and $\dot{x}_m$), given by the equation for $z_m$.

The relevant excerpt is as follows:

---

[image]

---

The equation for $z_m$ (where $z = x$, $z= \dot{x}$) is what I don't understand. I presume $n$ here is a time constant that allows a relative weighting for older or newer values. Is that correct?

What does the expression $t^{n+1}$ represent? Do they mean time raised to exponent of $(n+1)$? Or something else like time at sample $(n+1)$?

What about the integral? Do they mean a Laplace $s$? What do I do with this in a stepwise function? They explain that this ought to be solved using a stepwise iterative approach which is perfect because I am using stepwise finite difference modeling for the system I want to add this to.

In a finite difference model where $Δt$ is the time step per time sample, $n$ is a given coefficient for mean weighting, and where you have the displacement $x$/$x_m$ and velocity $\dot{x}$/$\dot{x}_m$ at the prior time step, in plain English or simple demonstrative code or line by line math, what would be an iterative solution they are suggesting for $z_m$ (ie. the current $x_m$ or $\dot{x}_m$)?

Thanks for any help. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The variable of the weighted mean value *z*<sub>m</sub> would convey a more expressive power if denoted as *z*<sub>mean</sub>. The RHS integral in formula (14) of your reference is a "g(x)-weighted average of f(x) on the interval [0, t]", see http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integ/integ04/integ04.html. In formula (14), *f(s)* is *z*<sup>2</sup>*(s)* and *g(s)* = *s*<sup>n</sup>. The integral in (14) is not a Laplace transform, but the extended g(x)-weighted mean value, and *s* is not a dual variable of the Laplace transform, but a dummy variable of integration.

A variable *n* in (14) is not an index but the exponent of the power function *g(s)* = *s*<sup>n</sup>, and *t* is also not indexed, but raised to a power *n+1*. From the fragment you presented in your question, and if they indeed use Newark's method, it does not follow that the authors seek an iterative solution for *z*<sub>m</sub>; rather, they use the weighted means as per formula (14) to find the solution for *x*, *x*_dotted.